# Year over Year Inflation Calculation for particular data model

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

*I know that this might be a duplicate question but I have failed to find a solution to my problem after about 5 hours of searching. Sorry in advance if it is.*

**The data**
I have three tables that are in the DIrectQuery Storage Mode. One is called LINE_ITEM it has a one to many relationship with another table INVOICE. The INVOICE table has a one to many relationship with another table CONTRACT. Each CONTRACT has one INVOICE per year. Each INVOICE has one or more line items, all of which have a N_PAID_AMOUNT.

[image: Screenshot of relevant Data Model as it appears in the power bi relationship view.]

**Goal**
I'm looking to calculate the percent increase in the amount paid each INVOICE year.

**Limitations**
This same pbix file will be used to do many other things and needs to be very responsive. I do not want to manipulate the queries or relationships in any way if possible for the sake of both speed and simplicity. I would like to solve this with a measured or calculated column.

**Where I'm stuck at**
I have a formula, which I am using in a measure

```
Previous Paid Amount = CALCULATE(SUM(LINE_ITEM[N_PAID_AMOUNT]), YEAR(INVOICE[DT_START]) = YEAR(INVOICE[DT_START])-1)
```

It throws an error "Cannot find name '[DT_START]'." only for the second occurance in the filter expression. If I replace the formula with,

```
Previous Paid Amount = CALCULATE(SUM(LINE_ITEM[N_PAID_AMOUNT]), YEAR(INVOICE[DT_START]) = NOW())
```

It does not throw errors but obviously does not help me calculate what I need.

**Other things I've tried**
I have tried using the EARLIER DAX function, I have tried changing the data to import mode, I have tried numerous other formulas and functions. I have tried all kinds of quick measures including the one that is supposed to do this exact calculation and none have been successful.

Let me know if there's any other information I can share to help you answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Paid Amount LY = 
CALCULATE(
    INVOICE[Paid Amount],
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('INVOICE'[Year]),
        ISONORAFTER('INVOICE'[Year], MAX('INVOICE'[Year])-1, DESC)
    )
) -
CALCULATE(
    INVOICE[Paid Amount],
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('INVOICE'[Year]),
        ISONORAFTER('INVOICE'[Year], MAX('INVOICE'[Year])-2, DESC)
    )
)
```

This formula solved my problem. However it is horrendous. If anyone has insight on how I could do this better please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try using PreviousYear DAX function,

```
Previous Paid Amount =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( LINE_ITEM[N_PAID_AMOUNT] ),
    PREVIOUSYEAR( INVOICE[DT_START] )
)
```

[Check this link for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousyear-function-dax)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, seems like progress. After pasting in your formula It does not show that there are any errors with the formula however when I insert the column into any kind of visual it fails to display the visual. it show the error "Could not load the data for this visual. Not a legal OleAut date.. The exception was raised by IDataReader interface."

Comment: Seems to be bad date data, Read a solution available on power bi community page. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/not-a-legal-oleaut-date-cannot-refresh/td-p/539658